# Which is the better word: “byproduct” or “waste”?

Tags: differences, nouns, synonyms

At the construction and demolition project we get a lot of waste. And some materials are going to be recycled to make new products.

Which word is more appropriate for describing these materials, *byproduct* or *waste*?

Comment: In civic administrator parlance 'waste' is an admission of failure.  In the UK, even the stuff that does not get recycled is said to 'go to landfill' (on which there is a heavy tax).

Comment: Generally, you wouldn't call it _waste_ if the material was actually being sold off. A term you hear these days is _reclaimed_, i.e _reclaimed timber/fireplaces/fixtures_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, the two words have different meanings.

*Waste* is something that has no use.
A *Byproduct* is something that does have use.

You would use whichever word was appropriate in the context.

However, in common use, recycling is an activity applied to *waste*.  In this case the word *byproduct* is often applied to the product that is made from the waste after the recycling.

Answer (score 1):

Byproduct seems like a softer word. When I think of "waste", I think of "devoid of function", not recyclable.